# Redux | Async | Can't figure out why dispatch function isn't working

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I can't figure out why the dispatch function in my action creator isn't running. I've imported redux-thunk in my store since it is an async function.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { LOG_IN } from './types'

export function signup ({email, password}) {
    console.log('signup function ran') // THIS RUNS
    return function (dispatch) {
        console.log('dispatch function ran') // THIS DOES NOT RUN, NOR DOES ANYTHING BELOW
        axios
        .post('https://MYAPI.com/signup', {email, password})
        .then(response => dispatch({
            type: LOG_IN,
            payload: response.data.token
        }))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out why returning the function within the function didn't work but the following code does work (I've bolded the changes I made). I'd love it if someone could let me know why the first didn't work, though :)

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { LOG_IN } from './types'
import store from '../store' // I IMPORTED THE STORE

export function signup ({email, password}) {
    console.log('singup function ran')
        axios
        .post('https://MYAPI/signup', {email, password})
        .then(response => store.dispatch({  // I SPECIFICALLY CALLED THE STORE HERE
            type: LOG_IN,
            payload: response.data.token
        }))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```